# I have about 100 "ghost" reminders stuck in Outlook/Exchange. How do I get rid of them?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

(I'm using Outlook 2013 and Exchange 2013.)

Based on very poor support I got from Microsoft a long time ago, I was advised to export my Exchange mailbox and then create a new one and re-import. This caused nothing but problems the biggest of which is that I am now stuck with incessant reminders on calendar events (meetings.)

When I "Dismiss" an event that has passed the dismissal seems to generate another reminder (not another event on my calendar, just the reminder.) Also, I think it's only the original reminder which, when dismissed, generates another reminder and that one itself, along with all the duplicates, continue to popup.

Over time I end up with more and more reminders for a single event and it's driving me crazy. I've now got 40 and 50 reminders (per calendar event) that I have to dismiss over the course of every day.

I've tried starting Outlook with `/cleanreminders` and `/cleansniff` on multiple occasions. They do nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MFCMapi usually works for this: [Deleting Ghost Reminders using MFCMapi](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ehlro/archive/2010/11/21/how-do-we-do-it-2-deleting-ghost-reminders-using-mfcmapi.aspx)

Steps:

1.) Create an Outlook Profile, in Online Mode.

2.) Launch MfcMapi.exe, select Session -> Logon and display Store Table, choose the profile created under the previous step, click OK.

3.) Double click your Mailbox.

4.) Expand the Root Container and double click the Reminders Folder.

5.) Sort by subject name ( you should be able to remember the name of the reminder that bothers you every day ).

6.) Select it, right click it , Delete it ( when asked, perform a hard delete ).

7.) YOU’RE DONE!

Link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ehlro/archive/2010/11/21/how-do-we-do-it-2-deleting-ghost-reminders-using-mfcmapi.aspx

Comment: "Page Not Found
Unfortunately, the page you've requested no longer exists. Please use the search form below to locate the information you're interested in."

Comment: Try this one http://blogs.technet.com/b/ehlro/archive/2010/11/21/how-do-we-do-it-2-deleting-ghost-reminders-using-mfcmapi.aspx

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.